# How can I decide which Operating System can control which processor..?

Tags: operating-system

The question actually is :

If I have some processor named x

I have 3 Operating Systems named a,b,c

Now how can I decide that which operating system controls the processor ?

What is the basic understanding between the processor and Operating system ?

And the above 3 operating systems are not of different versions from same company..

To be specific how Android hardware is different from iPhone hardware and why can't iOS be installed on Android hardware...??

Thanking you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually asking a question which shows your lack of understanding of OS, CPU and other technical terminologies.

Actually, You need to study the basic of Os and CPU to get a deep understanding on the topic. But, I will definitely help you out by defining both the terminologies.

Your computer's **operating system** has two main objectives in its management of the central processing unit, or CPU. First, the **OS** makes sure that as many processor cycles are used for work as possible.

Second, the OS schedules the processor's attention among the demands of different processes. Processes are actions that can be controlled and are the basic units of software with which the OS communicates. A process may be a task, such as a virus check, that runs in the background so you never even know it's working. It also may be one of several tasks that an application, such as a spreadsheet, executes at your request. In a multitasking OS, the OS has to switch the processor's attention between competing processes many times per second because the processor can only do one thing at a time.

Briefly summarizing :

A **processor** is the '**engine**' of the computer - it runs all the software and moves data around. The best processor in general has more cores (core i7), and a higher speed.

An **operating system** is the '**traffic cop**' of all the software on the computer - it's software that controls how all the other programs on the computer work together and share the resources of the computer.

Hope you have got an idea :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer..but I am not asking what does an OS do and what does a CPU do..My question is totally different from your answer I need why only specific software for some specific CPU ??

Comment: Ya, I understand. But, if you would have the knowledge about the same, you wouldn't have asked such a question. Just read the answer carefully and then ask yourself if your question is VALID????

Comment: Basically, just refer the link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing) , The question you have asked is actually termed as scheduling.

Comment: Ok..I understood the thing..If I am not wrong..the other OS doesn't get support from its non-specific hardware for scheduling the processes right ??

Comment: That's correct.. now you have understood all the 3 terminologies... nice